# undefined method `LastName' for nil:NilClass only on server

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, live, production

I dont know whats wrong, everything is working on localhost that too in production mode, but when I host it on heroku, I am having this problem. Please help me

```
    12: <% @myestate.each do |prop| %>
    13:     <% @name = User.find_by_id(prop.user_id) %>
    14:     <tr>
    15:       <td><%= link_to @name.LastName, management_show_path(:user_id => @name.id) %></td>
    16:     </tr>
    17: <% end %>
```

Application Trace

```
app/views/management/index.html.erb:15:in `block in _app_views_management_index_html_erb___3570841627314272835_37900600'
app/views/management/index.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_management_index_html_erb___3570841627314272835_37900600'
app/controllers/management_controller.rb:9:in `index'
```

Controller Index Action

```
  def index
    @myestate1 = Estate.where(:Mgmt => current_user.Company)
    @myestate = @myestate1.select("DISTINCT(user_id)")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @managements }
    end
  end
```

Error Message

```
undefined method `LastName' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this problem every once in a while. What I am seeing is that your `@name = User.find_by_id(prop.user_id)` (which tisk-tisk for code in the view controller) isn't finding anything, or at the very least `User.find_by_id(prop.user_id)` is returning nil. I am guessing User is a model class, have you seeded your database? Done your migrations? Those don't sync between development and deployment.

Comment: I dont think so thats the issue coz it cannot be nil.

Comment: `undefined method `LastName' for nil:NilClass` means that you are trying to call the method LastName on something that is nil. The only thing you are calling LastName on is `@name`. Therefore, either you aren't returning any users in your `User.find_by_id(prop.user_id)` method or all the users in your database are nil.